# Call jstl in java script error

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to run a jstl query when i click submit button in webpage(jsp).
(I'm developing web application on net beans using glassfish server)
Here is my code.

**Jsp**

```
<Input type="Button" class="form_submit" id="submit" value = "Submit" onclick="callQuery()"/>
```

**java script.**

```
<script>
    function callQuery(){
    <sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/IFPWAFCAD">
                    SELECT * FROM AST WHERE ST = 4 ;
                    ;
                </sql:query>
        document.getElementById("slaq").innerHTML=
                <table id="rounded-corner">
                    <!-- column headers -->
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${result.columnNames}">
                            <th><c:out value="${columnName}"/></th>
                            </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- column data -->
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rowsByIndex}" varStatus="loop">
                        <tr class="${loop.index % 2 ==0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                            <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                                <td style="font-size: 80%; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold"><c:out value="${column}"/></td>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
    }
</script>
```

I know this code is wrong.But im new to this . Just started learning .any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry . Im just newbie .Im trying to run query after the submit button is clicked . But when i clicked submit button .it doesnt showing any results .

Comment: This won't work. You can't call Java EL from JavaScript.

Comment: @See Balus C's  [article on JSP & JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)